git fetch succeeds but git fetch --all gives a public key error
I have successfully cloned a repository from a GitLab instance. The repository is called main. (It was named that long before most people started using main as a branch name. That's probably not terribly relevant, but it's maybe worth mentioning to avoid confusion.)
After a couple days, I wanted any new updates from other team members to be included in my local copy. So I ran the following:
git fetch --all
... and got:
Fetching origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), 556 bytes | 185.00 KiB/s, done.
From git.mycompany.com:core/main
 * [new branch]              TIC-123_Remove_deprecations -> origin/TIC-123_Remove_deprecations
Fetching main
myfirstname.mylastname@git: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: could not fetch main

But here's the interesting thing. Running this succeeds:
git fetch
... giving me this:
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), 547 bytes | 68.00 KiB/s, done.
From git.mycompany.com:core/main
 * [new branch]              abc/TIC-101_change_wording_in_translations -> origin/abc/TIC-101_change_wording_in_translations

This is not a public repository: There should either be a failure for both cases or for neither, from what I understand.
I have verified that the key in my ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub file is identical to the key that GitLab shows for my user, and that the key is not expired. (It has a month to go.) I have also verified that the repository still exists, and that I have access to it in GitLab.
Any idea how I can regain access to this repository?
===
EDIT: Running git remote -v shows the following:
main    ssh://git/core/main.git (fetch)
main    no-push (push)
origin  git@git.mycompany.com:core/main.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.mycompany.com:core/main.git (push)


Try git remote -v. From what I see, you have a remote named origin which works and one named main, which doesn't.

git fetch fetches from one remote — the remote of the current branch or origin. git fetch --all fetches from all remotes and you have two: git.mycompany.com:core/main which is ok and myfirstname.mylastname@git which is not ok. You have to decide if you need the second remote; if not — remove it, if yes — configure SSH key at the remote.

You have 2 remotes: main with fetch URL ssh://git/core/main.git, push disabled; and origin with URL git@git.mycompany.com:core/main.git for fetching and pushing. git fetch --all fetches from both remotes and it seems one doesn't have your SSH key. You can check that with git fetch main.
You have to decide if you need remote main; if not — remove it with git remote rm main; if yes — configure SSH key at the remote. Or may be fix the remote (add the login git): git remote set-url main ssh://git@git/core/main.git

Good answer. Using git remote -v on a colleague's machine gave me a good idea of which remotes to keep and remove.
